# "dscl . list /users" command on Mac to know if hacked

Tags: macos, multiple-users

I have a feeling that my macbook is hacked so I searched online and used the "`dscl . list /users`" to find out if there is any suspicious results. I got a huge list of weird names of users but I am such a computer and code noob like I literally can't tell if its part of normal software processes or if its actual viruses etc. I also used the "`dscl . -readall /Users`" to get more info on users and got results like:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000053
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/virusmails
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 83
RealName:
 AMaViS Daemon
RecordName: _amavisd amavisd
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 83
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
-
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000107
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/db/analyticsd
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 263
RealName:
 Analytics Daemon
RecordName: _analyticsd
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 263
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
-
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000111
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/db/appinstalld
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 273
RealName:
 App Install Daemon
RecordName: _appinstalld
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 273
UserShell: /usr/bin/false
```

I have no idea what any of this means but  pretty sure "`NFSHomeDirectory: /var/virusmails`" is a virus right? and `UserShell: /usr/bin/false` means its a user I can't trace back no?

Comment: You are not infected with a virus. Why are you concerned? Just randomly?

Answer (score 1):

No, the AMaViS Daemon scans emails for viruses (or it would if you had your Mac set up to act as a mail server). Setting a virtual user account's shell to `/usr/bin/false` just makes it so no one can log in to that account. For security's sake, we don't want background processes like antivirus scanners to run as root, so we give them fake accounts to run as. But we don't want hackers or malware to be able to use those fake accounts to log in, so we set the shell to something that's not a shell at all and in fact just immediately quits with an error code, which is what `/usr/bin/false` does.

Comment: Thanks Spiff. how about this, what does it mean?
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000116
NFSHomeDirectory: /var/db/accessoryupdater
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 278
RealName:
 Accessory Update Daemon
RecordName: _accessoryupdater
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 278
UserShell: /usr/bin/false

Comment: Are these normal software processes or weird users
list/users
_accessoryupdater
_adsklic
_amavisd
_analyticsd
_appinstalld
_appleevents
_applepay
_appowner
_appserver
_appstore
_ard
_assetcache
_astris
_atsserver
_audiomxd
_avbdeviced
_avphidbridge
_backgroundassets
_biome
_calendar
_captiveagent
_ces
_clamav
_cmiodalassistants
_coreaudiod
_coremediaiod
_coreml
_ctkd
_cvmsroot
_cvs
_cyrus
_darwindaemon
_datadetectors
_demod
_devdocs
_devicemgr
_diskimagesiod
_displaypolicyd
_distnote
_dovecot
_dovenull
_dpaudio
_driverkit
_eppc
_findmydevice
_fpsd

Comment: @SaraXzy All of those accounts that start with an underscore are the standard fake accounts for background processes so they aren't all running as root.

By the way, if you've never previously familiarized yourself with the deep internal technical details of your OS, you shouldn't bother to do so when you think you've been "hacked". There are plenty of arcane technical details that are perfectly normal but sound scary to someone who's both unfamiliar, and also feeling paranoid/panicky. Take your computer to a trusted infosec expert for forensic analysis, don't try to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks @spiff , yes you're probably right but I can't find any infosec experts in my area and tried contacting apple to ask about this but got no answers. It was just that my laptop started acting strange overheating and losing charge fast and same with my iphone so I wanted to look more in to it. Anyways now I understand that some processes operate under certain accounts and thats why they show up!